# Download Spanish–English translations (esp. conjugations) as Open Data

Tags: verbos, conjugación, recursos

I'm learning Spanish conjugations and using sites like [Conjugemos](http://conjuguemos.com/). I like these time-intensive conjugation drills since they drive conjugations into procedural memory: after a while in the exercise, I can conjugate the forms automatically without actively thinking.

However, these sites tend to be very limited in their range of verbs and likewise, they tend to ask for Spanish conjugations by referring to the mood/tense and person rather than the English version. To give an example from the site linked above:

[image]

Here, thinking about what is present perfect interrupts the "flow" in a very artificial way. I probably spend more time thinking about tenses then how to say something in Spanish.

---

Long story short, I was thinking about writing my own software for conjugation exercise. As such, I was looking for some downloadable database of Spanish–English conjugations. Ideally the data would contain a comprehensive list of common Spanish verbs, the full set of tenses and moods for all possible persons in both Spanish and English, be in an open format and have an open licence (if I come up with something better than what I've seen, I might open source the software or create an online version).

The best resource I've found so far is a [CC-BY-SA licensed list of 600 conjugated Spanish verbs in CSV](http://www.ghidinelli.com/free-spanish-conjugated-verb-database), with all the verb forms you'd care to think of. One slight hitch is that it only gives the English form of the verb in the first person for each form; e.g. "I had abandoned". Likewise 600 verbs is not so much,

So I'm wondering: are there other open sources of Spanish–English conjugations out there?

I would also be generally interested in downloadable Spanish–English translations for vocabulary as well.

Comment: I know there's also an Open Data SE, but I think this might be the better pick of the two.

Comment: I realize this isn't technically a request for a "learning" resource, but it strikes me as, in spirit, the same thing, as the question isn't actually about the Spanish Language. If others disagree with me, feel free to bring it up in Meta, or just vote to re-open.

Comment: Maybe if it were changed to how to generate such a list, but then it would almost certainly be better on stack overflow

Comment: I think it was a bit over-eager to use a mod vote to close this question and then engage debate. The question is clear and has verifiable answers, it is not a duplicate, it is not unclear, it is not too broad and it is not opinion-based. Also I think it would be of interest to others. Nothing in the public [on-topic](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) discussion suggests it as unsuitable. @Flimzy, since you seemingly admit that closing might be debatable, would it not be more reasonable to allow it to be voted closed rather than using a unilateral mod vote? Anyways, my 2c. :)

Comment: @badroit: Thank you for your comments. I've posted on [meta](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/362/12) about this, as my response became too long for a comment. :)

Comment: @Flimzy, thanks for the meta comment! Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to comment or answer on `meta`. I think your position is reasonable, but I think my position is reasonable too. I see that the rules can be interpreted one way or the other but in general, I think the benefit of any significant doubt should go towards leaving the question open. But leaving aside interpretation of the rules, your role as a mod is to serve the community within the scope it has defined. My question then is: *how is the community served by _unilaterally_ closing this question*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### OmegaWiki

Omegawiki is one of the largest databases you can find for free, which offers a multilingual dictionary in every language, with lexicological, terminological and thesaurus information provided  under a GNU Free Documentation License 1.2 and Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 Dual-Licensing.

You can download the data [here](http://www.omegawiki.org/Help:Downloading_the_data).

Comment: I cannot +1 (yet) but thanks for the link, I'll have a look.